# Converting SQR into SQL to run in SQL Developer

Tags: sql, peoplesoft, sqr

I am trying to convert (per010) SQR into a SQL to run in SQL Developer.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: Please revise your post to help us understand what the question is.  It's good to know what you are trying to do, but we cannot very well help you do that if we don't know where you're stumped.  What have you tried?  What was the result?  How is the result not working for you?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Developer, that means that you have to work with a single SQL.

If I remember correctly, PER010 is the Turnover report.  It would not be possible to turn this report into a single SQL since it pulls elements from multiple tables and multiple passes, for example Hires versus Terminations.